# How can I import the sample xml data into my Wordpress site?

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a premium `Wordpress` theme with sample data in `XML` format. I've installed the theme but cannot import the XML data so that I can see how the theme actually works. Can anybody please give me an idea how the XML data can be imported into Wordpress?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   Go  Wp-admin->tool->import->wordpress on click

    -> install importer plugin then import your xml.
```

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/

[image]